# why is this happening ? operator= and copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

I have the following classes:

```
class CRectangle
{
    CRectangle(string color);
    CRectangle(CRectangle &origin);
    /* Some more code */
};
```

and this other:

```
class CPlane
{
    /* Some more code */
    CRectangle boundingBox();
};
```

Why is it that I can do this? :

```
CRectangle rectangle1;
CRectangle rectangle2=rectangle1;
CRectangle rectangle3(rectangle1); //Copy constructor.
```

But I can't do this:

```
CPlane plane;
CRectangle rectangle4=plane.boundingBox();
CRectangle rectangle5(plane.boundingBox()); //Copy constructor.
```

If I need to me the last one work how can I do it? I suppose that maybe it has something to do with operator `=` but I don't know exactly.

Edit: to fix copy constructor. error still there.

Comment: Your copy contructor causes an infinite recursion (copying causes a copy which causes a copy which....)

Comment: For copy constructors, you should be taking the parameter as a const reference.

Comment: As a tip for the future, when something 'doesn't work', please include **exactly what doesn't work**, I.E. the text from the compiler/runtime error or the actual output vs. the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind rvalues to a non-`const` lvalue reference.

```
CRectangle rectangle3(rectangle1);
```

Here `rectangle1` is a non-`const` lvalue, so that's fine.

```
CRectangle rectangle5(plane.boundingBox());
```

`plane.boundingBox()` is a pure rvalue (prvalue), so `CRectangle&` cannot be bound to it.

Instead declare your copy constructor to take a `const` reference:

```
CRectangle(CRectangle const&);
```

Or additionally declare a move constructor (if desired).

Comment: I was looking at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/  I thought that CRectangle(CRectangle origin) was a correct copy constructor.

Comment: @IzonFreak What!? He explicitly says "or **my personal favorite way to create an infinite loop in C++**:".

Comment: i just check my code and i do have CRectangle(CRectangle & origin); it was just an error at doing this post.

Comment: @IzonFreak ... you aren't serious.

Comment: yes, i forgot  to put & in this post, but in my code it's there and the problem is still the same i can't  CRectangle rectangle5(plane.boundingBox());

Comment: Thank you very much! is working, but i'm not sure if i understand why. i just did this. CRectangle( CRectangle const&); Thank you again.

Comment: @IzonFreak  What??  You are unable to copy/paste?

Answer (score 5):

First syntax of your copy constructor request compiler for infinite recursion.

It should be:-

```
CRectangle(const CRectangle& origin);
```

Second, both call should work properly as both are calls to copy constrcutor.

```
CRectangle rectangle4=plane.boundingBox();
CRectangle rectangle5(plane.boundingBox());
```

Comment: Re "request compiler for infinite recursion", yes, but first of all it asks the compiler for an error diagnostic, because that declaration is invalid. I suspect the OP is not posting real code. Or else, he or she is using some very old or odd compiler.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf im using eclipse Luna, and im using real code, i make it work by doing this:  CRectangle box("azul"); box=plano.boundingBox("",""); but i wanted to try the second approach but  it wont let me.

Comment: @IzonFreak: Eclipse is an IDE, not the compiler. Usually with eclipse you're using g++ or clang. I would guess, if that declaration compiles, then it must be some very old version.